# jquery animate boxshadow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/w5aAn/877/

Below, i'm achieving the effect I wanted, but with a pending issue. Since i'm using a separate span and positioning it absolute over-top of a box with relative position. I can not access the inputs until after the animation is finished. I'm guessing the only way to alleviate this would be do something similar with just animating the border of the outer box? But nothing I was doing to animate box-shadow:inset was working.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wow">
    <span id="pulse"></span>
    <input id="form-input"/>
    <input id="form-input"/>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#wow {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#pulse {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px #6c95c3; 
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #6c95c3; 
position: absolute;
z-index: 20000;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#pulse').stop().animate({"opacity": 0}, "fast"); 
$('#pulse').effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 500,  function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) property:

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) an element can become the target of mouse events.

```
#pulse {
    pointer-events: none;
    ...
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5aAn/878/)

Comment: Awesome, looks like no IE support at all or Opera. But surprised I've never run into pointer-events, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I simply modified the z-index for #pulse, so it will be layered below your inputs.

```
#pulse {
    ...
    z-index: -20000;
}
```